# GlobalSuppressions being ignored from StyleCop when running 'dotnet build', floods CI with error messages to the point that it terminates

Tags: c#, .net

I have my unit tests being asserted via TravisCI. When it gets to the step `dotnet build` then the console gets flooded with many errors and the build terminates.

This all started happening when I moved my `GlobalSuppressions.cs` into the top level solution folder, as I wanted to apply StyleCop to all the projects instead of one of them and not copy/paste the file into all of them.

To do this, I used `Directory.build.props` as follows

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(SolutionDir)GlobalSuppressions.cs" />
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In any IDE (such as Rider, Visual Studio 2019) I will get no warnings in the project and GlobalSuppressions.cs is being correctly applied to all of my projects.

When I do `dotnet build` on any OS, it appears to not know that `GlobalSuppressions.cs` exists anymore and floods it with errors.

How do I get `dotnet build` to accept `GlobalSuppressions.cs` on build? I have no idea why it works fine with any developer when compiling via some IDE, but doesn't work from the command line.

Comment: This is a drive by... does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247206/suppressing-the-stylecop-warnings-at-the-global-level) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to take a different approach to solving this. I did the following:

1) Removed `GlobalSuppressions.cs` (or rather cut it out of the project but keep the file around in another place so I have rules to reference)

2) Looked up the PackageReference, which at the time of writing was on the latest version as follows:

```
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
```

3) Created a new file in the solution directory called `Rules.ruleset` (or whatever name you want) and then manually set the rules in this file from your old `GlobalSuppressions.cs`

4) Use `Directory.Build.props` with the following content so it gets applied to every project (note how the stuff from (2) is applied here), I set it to error on warning but you can obviously remove that if you want

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(SolutionDir)Rules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

5) **Most importantly** make sure to remove any empty `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet></CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` or `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet />` left over in any of your project files. If these are present, at the time of writing it will mess up code analysis and will assume everything is defaulted to being on (which you almost certainly do not want). Cutting them out from the `.csproj` file is sufficient

After doing the above, all my projects now are using the newest .NET StyleCop analysis and it applies to all projects in my solution automatically.

**A final note**: Be careful when doing this, one time it decided to apply a bunch of styling fixes without my permission and mutated thousands of files.

EDIT: Note that VS can be a pain and starts inserting `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet />` for no reason even with the Directory.Build.props being present. I am not sure why it does this or what triggers it, but sometimes I have to delete it. I may have to change it such that `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(SolutionDir)Rules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` is manually set in every `.csproj` file if it continues to do this. We will see.